# Select specified content from a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want do build a small "listbox" selection in jquery.

```
<div id="first">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">abc1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">abc2</a></li>
</ul>
```

i wanted to create first a function, if i click on the href, the class 'active' shoud be add, if its already added, i wanted to remove this.

```
$('#first').click( function(e)
                 {
                     $('a[href=#]').click( function(e)
                                           {
                                              alert('bla');   
                                           })


                 })
```

but he is doing the alert 3 times :-/

look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MATW/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your idea is to add or remove the class active to the corresponding anchor tag i dont think you need to have a click function on on the div that contains the list.. all u need to do is

```
  $('#first a').click(function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the useful method [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to help with that:

```
$('#first').click( function(){
    $('a[href=#]').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        // Disable native click
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ui thanks, but is it normal, in jsfiddle, he add the class but remove it look : http://jsfiddle.net/9MATW/2/

Comment: @Roby sorry, your example isn't very clear, and is significantly different to what I've posted. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want at most a single link made active – so when one is clicked and another one is already active, make the other one inactive first – or just as many as are clicked?

Comment: the enxt step would be to get a list of all "active" hrefs i mean the name like : abc, abc1, abc2

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method for going through a series of elements

Comment: youre right :) thanks. but how can i say i only want from the class id first all hrefs ?